# 2003 Ford Escape

Tags: brakes

I just got my 2003 Ford Escape and my brake pedal has been replaced . When I first go to pull out from being parked (mostly only happens on dirt road ) my brake pedal pulsates and makes kind of a rubbing noise and I have to slowly come to a complete stop and pump my brakes a few times then it doesn’t do it anymore . I’ve already changed the rotor thinking it was warped

Comment: You said "when I first go to pull out", are you saying that you are pressing the brake?  Can you make it a bit clearer what you are doing when it happens?

Comment: When I first start my car and move it , the first time I have to press my brake whether I’m going down my drive way or having to slow down , that’s when it does it .

Answer (score 0):

This fits the description of the ABS system is being activated.  Putting in the issue of having to pump the brakes, creates the possibility of air in the brake system. First a brake bleed should be done.

Afterwards the ABS module should be scanned for error codes and with the scanner check that each wheel speed sensor correlates with each other. If not the speed sensor at fault should be serviced or replaced.

It should be said that sudden braking will cause the ABS to activate on gravel roads. This is normal. Bit if they activate during light braking you have a problem.

Comment: I’ve already bled the brakes , when I go to pull out anywhere , and When I have to press my brakes for the first time is when it does it , not when I sudden brake. I can barley press then and be going really slow and it still does it

Comment: The ABS module should be scanned for error codes and with the scanner check that each wheel speed sensor correlates with each other. If not the speed sensor at fault should be serviced or replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Things I would check for :

- Calliper partially seizing
- Worn wheel bearing
- Faulty abs sensor

All of these can cause ABS issues.

The callipers are easy to compare to each other for unevenness.  Significant play in a wheel bearing should be easy to detect.  A multimeter can give an indication of whether an abs sensor is faulty.